# Concatenate layer in Keras makes fitting fail

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Whenever I concatenate the outputs of two layers (for example, because I want to use softmax on some outputs and another activation function on the rest), the network always fails to learn.

This is some example code to demonstrate the problem:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Dense, Concatenate, Dropout, Reshape, \
                                    Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.losses import mse, categorical_crossentropy, binary_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model, to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import os
import pygameVisualise as pyvis

# MNIST dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

no_cls = max(y_train)+1
width = 20

extra_dims = True

image_size = x_train.shape[1]
original_dim = image_size * image_size
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, [-1, original_dim])
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, [-1, original_dim])
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=width if extra_dims else no_cls)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=width if extra_dims else no_cls)

hidden_dim = 512
batch_sz = 256
eps = 10

ins = Input(shape=(original_dim,))
x = Dense(hidden_dim)(ins)
cls_pred = Dense(no_cls, activation="softmax")(x)
other    = Dense(width-no_cls)(x)
outs = Concatenate()([cls_pred, other])

encoder = Model(ins, outs if extra_dims else cls_pred, name="encoder")
encoder.summary()

def cust_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    return categorical_crossentropy(y_true[:no_cls], y_pred[:no_cls])

optimiser = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.003, clipvalue=0.1)
encoder.compile(optimizer=optimiser, loss=cust_loss_fn,
                metrics=["accuracy"])

encoder.fit(x_train, y_train,
            batch_size=batch_sz,
            epochs=eps,
            validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = encoder.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(score)

print(encoder.predict(x_train[0:10]))
```

With `extra_dims = False`, i.e. no concatenate layer, the network will consistently reach 88% accuracy in the 10 epochs. When it is `True`, the network will stay at around 8% accuracy and the loss will not drop at all during training.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the model runs? Since that way of slicing in the loss function is wrong as it is only selecting the first `no_cls` samples and therefore the shapes would not be consistent. It must be `[:,:no_cls]` instead.

Comment: @today Thank you so much, I changed that line and it started learning, although much slower than before - guess this was to be expected though. Thanks for pointing it out! Wonder why this works without the concatenate layer though? Wasn't having any problems with `extra_dims = False`

Comment: It does not run and gives me errors when I use `keras` directly. I did not test it using `tensorflow.keras` and I don't know why it works with that. It's strange indeed.